# How to call Form2 in Form1

Tags: c#

I'm doing a shop with 7 forms, the form 1 is the basic of the store with picture's Box and a textbox saying how much should I pay. When I click in the picture's box, for example in a T-shirt, it opens a new Form with some information and a button saying "add to cart". 
Basically I want to click on the button "add to cart" and then the Form2 closes and back's to form 1 and in the textbox (that shows how much should I pay) shows the value.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please try to improve the clarity of your question, see [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Forms are objects like any other, and you can pass references to them and call methods on them like any other.

For example, let's say you expose a method on `Form1` which accepts the value and updates the UI:

```
public void UpdatePayAmount(double amount)
{
    // use the supplied value to update your text box
}
```

Then you would want to call that method from `Form2` when clicking on the "Add to Cart" button.  Something like:

```
form1Instance.UpdatePayAmount(someAmountValue);
```

So your `Form2` code needs a reference to an instance of `Form1` in a variable somewhere.  Since `Form2` now depends on `Form1`, a sensible place to put that requirement would be in its constructor.  Perhaps populating a private field:

```
private Form1 form1Instance;

public Form2(Form1 form1)
{
    form1Instance = form1;
}
```

Now `Form2` requires a reference to an instance of `Form1` when you create it, so it can call a method on that instance when the button is clicked.  So when you create `Form2` in your `Form1` code you would supply that instance:

```
form2 = new Form2(this);
form2.Show();
```